# Is it possible to update Secondary Tile's DisplayName?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've a secondary tile created like this:

```cs
SecondaryTile tileData = new SecondaryTile() { TileId = "MyId", DisplayName = "MyOldName", Arguments = "none" };
tileData.VisualElements.Square150x150Logo = new Uri(MediumImage);
tileData.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;
return await tileData.RequestCreateAsync();
```

The tile has been created successfully and I can see its [*DisplayName*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile.displayname). Now when I want to update image, it can be done via *TileUpdater*:

```cs
TileUpdater tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile("MyId");
var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);
// ... and so on
```

but what about the *DisplayName* - when looking at [tile template catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#medium_image-only_templates), there is none, which could be used to change tile's *DisplayName* - is it possible somehow?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 (maybe also for Windows Phone 8.1) you can use [`AsyncUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile.updateasync):

```
_secondaryTile.DisplayName = newDisplayName;
await _secondaryTile.UpdateAsync();
```

Comment: Hmmm, the MSDN you have linked says: *This method does not update these properties: DisplayName...*. Have you tried this?

Comment: That's strange.  Yeah I tried it and it's working for me :)

Comment: Maybe they have changed something without changing the docs, I will try this in upcoming days.

Answer (score 0):

Very possible:

```
//change main name (DisplayName)
var tiles = await SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync();
foreach (var tile in tiles)
{
    tile.DisplayName = localtime2;
    tile.UpdateAsync();
}
```